# How to use dash loading at certain points in the app

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to set up the dash loading component for n less than 5. And after 5 it should disappear and before 5, only the loading component shows. unfortunately, it still shows after interval 5 and it shows with other components. How can I approach this?

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Interval(id='interval-test', interval=1000, disabled =False),
    dcc.Loading(
            id="loading-1"),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='demo-dropdown',
    options=[
        {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
        {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
        {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
    ],
    value='MTL'),
    
    daq.BooleanSwitch(
        on=True,
        color="#9B51E0"),
    
    daq.LEDDisplay(
    label="Test LED",
    value='1.001',
    backgroundColor="#FF5E5E"),

    html.H1(id='test-output1'),
    html.H1(id='test-output2')

])


@app.callback(Output("loading-1", 'children'),
               Input('interval-test', 'n_intervals'))
def interval_update(n):
     if n<=5:
         return n
     else:
         PreventUpdate
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to link the loading component up to when your app is actually loading? You could just wrap everything in the loading component, and it would show/hide on its own when things load without the need for a callback. That's more of the intended use for that component. Trying to manually turn it on and off is a job better suited something you make yourself, such as text saying "Loading..." which you show or hide with a callback.

Comment: Because I am using dcc intervals to update my graphs, when I use it that way it shows the loading icon evry 1 second. I only want it to show once before my graphs are ready

Comment: I think you may be better off creating a custom loading component, in that case.

Comment: Please do you have any docs that show how to create my loading component?

Comment: I do not, but you could create one as simply as placing an opaque `div` over everything, which you control with a callback to set it's `style` prop to `display='none'` or change its `className` prop to a CSS classname that will hide it. That div could contain text, or other elements that you want to show while loading.

Comment: @JA-pythonista - Did you find any alternative ?

Comment: I did find but the dash interval squeezed the graphs after loading. Its problematic